# problem using rostopic pub

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

i am trying to use rostopic pub to control the motors from the keyboard. i try to publish to the subscribed topic
/katana_arm_controller/joint_movement_action/goal
but i have to type header,goal_id , goal
which i don't know. i tried to read the published

/katana_arm_controller/joint_movement_action/result
but i get error message
ERROR: Cannot load message class for [katana_msgs/JointMovementActionResult]. Are your messages built?

what should i do?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71161/problem-using-rostopic-pub/) by [rem870](https://answers.ros.org/users/5383/rem870/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2013-08-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-08-05**:
Is the package path in `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` variable? Does the package have msg folder within?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried useing the auto complete function by pressing tab. Every time I wanted to control our Katana I got the raw message by pressing tab. I just had to add the joint names and joint values.

Here's what I did: Type:
rostopic pub /katana_arm_controller/joint_movement_action/goal katana_msgs/JointMovementActionGoal

now you should see a raw/empty message.

Note that auto complete does not work for me if I added -1 after "pub". I had to add it after pressing tab.

This command works for me:

```
rostopic pub -1 /katana_arm_controller/joint_movement_action/goal katana_msgs/JointMovementActionGoal "header:
seq: 0
  stamp:
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: ''
goal_id:
  stamp:
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  id: ''
goal:
  jointGoal:
    header:
      seq: 0
      stamp: {secs: 0, nsecs: 0}
      frame_id: ''
    name: ['katana_motor1_pan_joint', 'katana_motor2_lift_joint', 'katana_motor3_lift_joint', 'katana_motor4_lift_joint', 'katana_motor5_wrist_roll_joint']
    position: [-1.0025087725759727064, -0.304799451742457883, 0.703302076077451588, -0.0062867086188651555, -1.00085111164]
    velocity: [0]
    effort: [0]"
```

Moving the gripper also does not work.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2013-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rem870](https://answers.ros.org/users/5383/rem870/) on 2013-08-05**:
Hi, thanks for your answer
i left everything as is except from
name: ['katana_motor1_pan_joint,']
position: [-1.69906439143]

which i copied from a previus reading of positions and it worked

thanks

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-08-05**:
@rem870 please accept the question using the checkbox at the left so others know this worked for you.